# Postgres rotate cron backups

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, cron, backup

I`m trying to make a script which will make following:

Connect to postgres database, make dump, gzip dump and store to dir.

All this must be rotated - 24 backups for day, 7 for week

File name must contain date, hour and minutes in file name.

Old ones must be deleted (I dont want more backus as described)

This script will run every hour trough cron.

I wrote this script (change some found at web) but there are some bugs:

1) It says: "awk: line 1: syntax error at or near end of line"

2) when I run script it on overwrites dayly backup and don`t make new one

3) hour backup make only folder with name "hourly" and didn`t make backup

4) all backups will be backed up to synology NAS via rsync

Can anyone help me please?

Script backup.sh:

```
# !/bin/bash

# for use with cron, eg:
# 0 3 * * * postgres /var/db/db_backup.sh example_db

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <example_db> [pg_dump example_db]"
    exit 1
fi

DB="$1"; shift
DUMP_EXAMPLE_DB=$@
DIR="/var/db/backups/$DB"

KEEP_HOURLY=24
KEEP_DAILY=7
KEEP_WEEKLY=5
KEEP_MONTHLY=12

function rotate {
    rotation=$1
    fdate=`date +%Y-%m-%d-$H -d $date`
    file=$DIR/daily/*$fdate*.gz
    mkdir -p $DIR/$rotation/ || abort
    if [ -f $file ]; then
        cp $file $DIR/$rotation/ || abort
    else
        echo
    fi
}

function prune {  
    dir=$DIR/$1
    keep=$2
    ls $dir | sort -rn | awk " NR > $keep" | while read f; do rm $dir/$f; done
}

function abort {
    echo "aborting..."
    exit 1
}

mkdir -p $DIR/hourly || abort
mkdir -p $DIR/daily || abort
mkdir -p $DIR/weekly || abort
mkdir -p $DIR/monthly || abort
mkdir -p $DIR/yearly || abort

date=`date +%Y-%m-%d` || abort
hour=`date -d $date +%H` || abort
minute=`date -d $date +M` || abort
day=`date -d $date +%d` || abort
weekday=`date -d $date +%w` || abort
month=`date -d $date +%m` || abort

# Do the daily backup
/usr/bin/pg_dump $DB $DUMP_EXAMPLE_DB | gzip > $DIR/daily/${DB}_$date.gz
test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 || abort

# Perform rotations
if [[ "$weekday" == "0" ]]; then
    rotate weekly
fi
if [[ "$hour/$minute" == "0/0" ]]; then
    rotate hourly
fi
if [[ "$day" == "01" ]]; then
    rotate monthly
fi
if [[ "$month/$day" == "01/01" ]]; then
    rotate yearly
fi

prune hourly $KEEP_HOURLY
prune daily $KEEP_DAILY
prune weekly $KEEP_WEEKLY
prune monthly $KEEP_MONTHLYOD
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you want to accomplish with this line: `ls $dir | sort -rn | awk " NR > $keep" | while read f; do rm $dir/$f; done`? The `awk` part is quite odd.

Comment: I have no idea. I have found this script over the net and trying to change for my needs. If you have any idea what I must change to make it work please help :-)